# How do I fix Typescript subcribable interface error?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I am trying to migrate a production Angular application from 7 to 8.  When I try to build I get the following error:

```
ERROR in app/vehicle/vehicle.component.ts:90:36 - error TS2344: Type 'IOwnerVehicle' does not satisfy the constraint 'ObservableInput<any>'.
Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type 'IOwnerVehicle' but required in type 'Iterable<any>'.

90             flatMap<IVehicleOwner, IOwnerVehicle>(owner => {
                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  ../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts:43:5
    43     [Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<T>;
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    '[Symbol.iterator]' is declared here.
```

I believe I have found a clue to the source of the problem in the **TypeScript Subscribable interface issue topic** in the [RXJS Subscribable documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~SubscribableOrPromiseDoc.html).  But I still can't figure out how to solve the problem.

VSCode shows no errors in the vehicle component.  I thought the numbers following the ts file should represent line and column, but the component is only 50 lines long and line 36 is blank.

The Subscribable docs say something about "TypeScript has problem supporting interfaces with methods defined as symbol properties.", but the IOwnerVehicle interface is only a property bag.  It has no methods.

The only code having anything to do with a subscription is the constructor

```js
   constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private owner: IVehicleOwner,
      private svc: SearchService,
      private searchDlg: MatDialogRef<OwnerVehicleComponent, IOwnerVehicle>) {
      this.svc.getOwnerVehicles(owner.id.toString()).subscribe(
         list => {
            if (list.length > 0)
               this.list = list;
            else
               this.searchFailed = true;
         });
   }
```

And the service couldn't be simpler

```js
   getOwnerVehicles(vehicleId: string): Observable<IOwnerVehicle[]> {
      const url = `${this.webApi}/vehicle`;
      return this.http.get<IOwnerVehicle[]>(url,
         {params: {owner : vehicleId}});
   }
```

Can someone help me figure out what I need to change or where else I need to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at the type of `flatMap`:

```
declare function mergeMap<T, O extends ObservableInput<any>>(project: (value: T, index: number) => O, concurrent?: number): OperatorFunction<T, ObservedValueOf<O>>;
```

As you see, `flatMap`'s second generic, extends `ObservableInput`. So in your code, `IOwnerVehicle` which seems to be a simple interface, should actually be `ObservableInput<IOwnerVehicle>`.

So just change your code to:

```
flatMap<IVehicleOwner, ObservableInput<IOwnerVehicle>>(owner => {})
```

And you should be able to find it in `vehicle.component.ts` line 90 column 36